# Conflicting event-handling in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="Field1">
  <label id="label1">Name</label><br/>
  <input type="text" data-attr="text" style="..." id="input1"/><br/>
  <label id="instr1"/>
  <div class="xfb-row-options1">
    <a class="button-delete" src="..." style="...">-</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I already have a jQuery function:

```
$("#fb_contentarea_col1down21 div").live("click", function(){
  // some stuff to change the properties of the Field,
  // like changing the field name, size.
  return false;
});
```

I have a `<div>` with a "delete" image button inside it, and I want to delete this  on clicking "`button-delete1`". I tried it with:

```
$("#fb_contentarea_col1down21 div div .button-delete1").live("click", function(){
  //deleting the Div Field1
  return false;
});
```

Now both my functions conflict. When I click on "`button-delete1`", my function #1 gets executed and shows me an error.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [remove](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove) method to delete the div, and [stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29) from causing the click event on the delete button from firing the click event on the parent div:

```
  $("#fb_contentarea_col1down21 div div .button-delete1").live("click", function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      $("#Field1").remove();
      return false;
  });
```